# Multiple lock single unlock in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I am implementing my version of `RunnableFuture` and faced the need to atomize state change at the end of `run()` method. The specific list of state fields does not matter. The point it that `Runnable` may finish either by exception, or normally. Hence it can either visit tail of `try` block, or not. Also I can visit `catch` block, then `finally` block.

All these 3 places should be changed atomically, but I can't see "interblock" locking construction. So, I used `getHoldCount()` to decide whether to call `lock()`:

```
public void run() {

      Runnable runnable;

      lock.lock();
      try{
         runnable = this.runnable;
         done = false;
         running = true;
         result = null;
      }
      finally {
         lock.unlock();
      }

      try {
         if( !cancel ) {
            runnable.run();
         }

         if( lock.getHoldCount()==0 ) lock.lock();
         exception = null;
         result = finalResult;

      }
      catch (Exception e) {

         if( lock.getHoldCount()==0 ) lock.lock();

         exception = e;
         result = null;

      }
      finally {
         if( lock.getHoldCount()==0 ) lock.lock();
         done = true;
         running = false;

         lock.unlock();
      }

   }
```

Is this correct and is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Does this involve one thread suspending execution which might be notified by another?

Answer (score 1):

Why not chaining `try-finally` statements:

```
try {
    lock.lock();
    // Do something ...
} finally {
    try {
        // Do more ...
    } finally {
        try {
            // Do more ...
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

}
```

Comment: @Dims You can optionally add `catch` blocks. The `finally` blocks will always execute, it doesn't matter whether there has been an exception or not.

Comment: So, how to execute both catch and finally in one atom?

Comment: @Dims Your first statement locks. All the following statements (the comments in the code example) keep the lock until it gets released in the last and most inner `finally` statement. As written in my previous comment, you can just add catch blocks between any of the try and finally statements, the lock is held all the time and safely released at the end. Tell me if I should edit the example. (It is quite straightforward though.)

Comment: I can't lock before calling `Runnable`, since it should run in concurrent mode. Also, I can't lock after calling `Runnable`, since in the case of exception, it will skip lock statement.

Comment: @Dims In case of what exception? `lock.lock()` can be the first statement in `run`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98136/discussion-between-steffen-and-dims).

Answer (score 0):

Any time the logic gets complex enough that I have to ask, "will this work?"  I break it up into subroutines:

```
public void run() {
    setup();
    exception ex = doRun();
    report(ex);
}

private void setup() {
    lock.lock();
    try{
        done = false;
        running = true;
        result = null;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

private Exception doRun() {
    try {
        if( !cancel ) {
            this.runnable.run();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return e;
    }
    return null;
}

private void report(Exception ex) {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        done = true;
        running = false;
        if (ex != null) {
            exception = ex;
            result = null;
        } else {
            exception = null;
            result = finalResult;
        }
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```